# How to set proper system instructions to openai chat bot?

Tags: python, openai-api

I have a task to make a chatbot prototype for our company using Openai API.
The problem is that it forgets system instructions.

```
import openai
import streamlit as st
from utils import chat_completion_request,generagte_dataframe,functions,execute_function_call
import json

with st.sidebar:
    openai_api_key = st.text_input("OpenAI API Key", key="chatbot_api_key", type="password")

    "[Get an OpenAI API key](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys)"
    

df =generagte_dataframe()

st.title(" Helpful Chat Bot")
if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["messages"] = [{"role": "system",
 "content": """You are virtual assistant and help workers with payment related questions.
        Don't make assumptions about what values to plug into functions.
                  Ask for clarification if a user request is ambiguous.
 Dont plug empty values into functions.
                 Dont answer any unrelated questions"""},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "How can i help you?"}]
    


for msg in st.session_state.messages:

    if msg["role"]!="system":
        st.chat_message(msg["role"]).write(msg["content"])



if prompt := st.chat_input():
    if not openai_api_key:
        st.info("Please add your OpenAI API key to continue.")
        st.stop()

    openai.api_key = openai_api_key
    
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})

    st.chat_message("user").write(prompt)

    response=chat_completion_request(messages=st.session_state.messages,functions=functions)
   
    msg = response.json()['choices'][0]['message']
    

    if msg.get('function_call'):
        results = execute_function_call(df,msg)
        st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": results})

        st.chat_message("assistant").write(results)
    
    if msg['content']:
        st.session_state.messages.append(msg)
        # print( st.session_state.messages)
        st.chat_message("assistant").write(msg['content'])
```

Next in streamlit when  I ask:
"Who is the president of the France?"
It says:
"I am virtual assistant to help workers and can answer only related questions"
Next time it answers after rerun:
"Emanuel Macron"

It seems the model sometimes pays attention to context and sometimes doesn't.
Are there any hints to solve this? Or one should use chat-gpt-4 model only?